# Name of an inductively defined sequence of graphs

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $G_k$ be the graph obtained by applying the following procedure k-times:

1. Start with a graph with single vertex $v$ (Call this graph $H$)
2. Add a vertex $u$ such that $u$ is not adjacent to any vertex of $H$ (i.e., $K:= H \cup \{u\}$) union of two graphs
3. Add a vertex $w$ such that $w$ is adjacent to all the vertices of $K$ (i.e., $J := K \vee \{w\}$) join of two graphs
4. Set $H = J$
5. Goto step 2.

My question is, is there a name for the class of graphs $\{G_k\}_{k\ge1}$? Please provide some references. Thank you.

Comment: Is it the join of $\overline{K_{k+1}}$ and $K_k$? I doubt if there is a name.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay, no. The initial vertex $v$ from step 1 and the $w$ vertices form $K_{k+1}$, and the $u$ vertices have degrees $1$ to $k$ because (indexing by iteration at which they're added) $u_i - w_j$ iff $i \le j$.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Right, my mistake.  I still doubt if there's a name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not quite the same question, but the graphs that can be obtained by repeating either of the two operations (add a disjoint vertex or a dominating vertex), not necessarily in strict alternation, are called [threshold graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threshold_graph).

Comment: Thank you. I am hearing this term for the first time :) . I will check the link and the iterature. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

As David Eppstein remarked, those graphs will all be [threshold graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threshold_graph). Moreover, they will be [universal threshold graphs](https://doi.org/10.1017/S096354830000122X), in the sense that $G_k$ contains all threshold graphs on $k+1$ vertices. This is also discussed in Section 4.1.6 of [Michael Engen's thesis](https://github.com/engenmt/doctoral-dissertation/blob/main/mainFile.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the comments and the nice references :)   .